# Removing Stencils from Visio Document

Tags: c#, visio

Is there any ways to remove an existing Stencil from a Visio Document ?
(`C# Win App`)

---

I Couldnt find a way to remove an existing stencil. 
But here is a sample to Add 1.

```
VisioDrawing.Document.Application.ActiveDocument.OpenStencilWindow();
VisioDrawing.Document.Application.Documents.OpenEx(_StencilPath + "BASFLO_M.vss",
(short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
```

Comment: please include in your question what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply close the open stencil, e.g.:

```
VisioDrawing.Document.Application.Documents.Item("BASFLO_M.vss").Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple documents open using the same stencil, you should be able to just close the stencil window for the drawing.  That way, you don't close stencils from other documents.

So to do this, you'd find the window for the document from within Visio.Application.Windows, then look through that Window's window list, and for each one see if its document is the one you want to close.  Then you just call the close method on that window.  When you save the file, the stencil is no longer attached to that drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want/need the stencils to load you can rename the Visio Content folder that stores the stencils.

For Visio2013 it's C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Visio Content\1033.  Add a new folder and dump the files in there. This hides the stencils so that Visio cant see them. Then launch your Visio file.